# Commenting breaks when debug is set to off

Tags: django, django-comments, mezzanine

comments work fine when debug is on but when I turn it off I get "an error occurred" message and it fails to redirect me back to the original page, instead showing the error message at url "www.MYSITE/comments". I'm using django threaded comments on Mezzanine if that helps. I'd just like a way to see the error message at least. Best,

jake

Comment: Could you explain a little more, what is a "comment" what apps you have, etc...

Comment: Sorry I thought I did, but again, I'm using django threaded comments (http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/) via Mezzanine (http://mezzanine.jupo.org/). If you need any more info let me know specifically what you need and you got it (I'm new at this!)

Comment: just letting me know how to get error messages from a site with debug off would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process-exception), more precisely the `process_exception` part? You can write your own middleware class to log the exception or display it in the result page.